# USB2, USB3, iPad 2 and iPad Pro

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, usb, data-transfer

I have one USB 2 and one USB 3 hub, both connected to a USB3 port of my mac. The USB 3 hub has a small number of ports, so I have to pick exactly what will use that hub. Both hubs are powered. I have one iPad 1, an iPad 2, an iPad Pro, an Apple TV4 and an iPhone 6. I develop apps for iOS, so I need these devices to be connected on the right hub for them. Will it make any difference to connect them on the USB 2 or 3 hub? I mean in terms of data transmission speed. I don't want to waste a USB 3 fast port on a slow device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of August 2017, only the **12.9” and 10.5” iPad Pro** (*not the 9.7” iPad Pro*) support USB 3 transfer speeds. No other iPad, iPhone, iPod, or tv does.

This is confirmed by Apple’s Store page for the [Lightning-to-USB 3 Camera Adapter](http://www.apple.com/us-hed/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter):

> The 12.9-inch iPad Pro and 10.5-inch iPad Pro transfer data at USB 3 speeds, while the 9.7-inch iPad Pro uses USB 2.

The problem is that the USB-to-Lightning cable Apple provides is only a USB **2** cable. You’d need a USB **3.0**-to-Lightning cable, or some kind of adapter, to benefit from the greater transfer speeds. Those do not exist yet, and even [Apple’s USB-C to Lightning Cable](https://support.apple.com/HT204360) only supports data transfer at up to USB 2.0 (480 Mbps) speeds.

Furthermore, **System Information** lists my iPhone 7+ as having a maximum transfer speed of 480 Mbps when connected to one of the main USB 3 ports on my iMac. This is consistent with USB 2 transfer speeds, which confirms that so far, no iPhone supports USB 3 transfers, at least not with Apple’s official Lightning cables.

[image: iPhone 7+ Maximum Transfer Speed]

It’s unclear whether the 4th generation tv supports USB 3 transfers. It does include a USB Type-C port, but that doesn’t necessarily mean it supports USB 3 speeds. For what it’s worth, there’s a USB **2**-to-Ethernet chip inside TV 4, per [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Apple+TV+4th+Generation+Teardown/49046#s107486). I doubt Apple would include a USB 3 port in tv, when most users would rarely, if ever use it, while leaving other devices with USB 2 that would benefit from USB 3.

If you want to be certain, plug your tv 4 into one of your Mac’s builtin USB 3 ports, and check **System Information**.

In summary: **Connect your Apple mobile devices to the USB 2 hub.**

Comment: can I ask where did you get this information?

Comment: Amended my Answer with additional details/sources. Apologies for any inaccuracies in my original answer 

Comment: Wonderful Information!!! Had the same question.

Comment: "The USB-C to Lightning Cable supports data transfer at up to USB 2.0 (480 Mbps) speeds." https://support.apple.com/HT204360